# Tag "gwan" synonym for existing tag "g-wan"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

At the time of this question is written:

- a search about "g-wan" returns 113 entries (the existing tag)
- a search about "gwan" returns 38 entries

Since there is no possible confusion with other tags, creating the synomym would help readers to find the relevant contents and to avoid duplicates.

I am requesting opinions to vote this suggestion up because I have a reputation of 1,196 points on Stackoverflow (not enough to create this synonym).

UPDATE (following a reply that does not answer the question):

[g-wan] and [gwan] DO NOT give the "same results" at all (different questions are returned), not to mention the order (either "Newest" or "Relevance") which is ALSO different

Comment: This has Eliza Doolittle all over it.

Comment: @random or [The Mad Stuntman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dr4Q09H_sFY)

Comment: @Gil, your edit makes little sense searching for `[gwan]` returns nothing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gwan

Comment: [gwan] returns nothing because it DOES NOT exists - and that's exactely what I am requesting you to do: to create it.

Comment: Ah, well that's a completely different question to the one you asked. You can't create a tag without a question to attach it to. You also can't create one if it's identical to another with the hyphens removed. So, in this case the answer is no. It's impossible to create the tag as it's already identical to [g-wan]. If there are questions about g-wan that are not tagged this way you can make the suggestion.

Comment: So my question was down-voted and ridiculed because people did not take the time to read it. Maybe the judges could have some kind of introspection - at least from time to time...

Answer (score 6):

I think you are confused. Just searching for the term "g-wan" and "gwan" doesn't imply they are tags. **There is only one tag [g-wan](/questions/tagged/g-wan) with 56 questions under it.**

Further, a synonym of [g-wan](/questions/tagged/g-wan) `<--` [gwan](/questions/tagged/gwan) is **completely useless** because typing "g-wan" or "gwan" into the tag box will yield the *exact same* results.

So, there's nothing to do here.

Comment: [g-wan] and [gwan] DO NOT give the *"same results"* at all (different questions are returned), not to mention the order (either "Newest" or "Relevance") which is ALSO different.

Comment: @Gil There is no [tag:gwan], only [tag:g-wan]. You are confusing tag searches (e.g. `[g-wan]`) with plain text searches (searching for `g-wan` and `gwan` returns different results, but this has nothing to do with tags).

Comment: I only state that if [gwan] existed as a synonym then the two searches would lead to the same results (which is not the case). Why punish me (down-votes and insults) instead of answer my question? *Is this really a "neutral" and "informative" behavior?*

Comment: If it existed as a synonym, your searches *wouldn't* lead to the same results. A tag search is not the same as a text search. A text search doesn't look at the tags at all, it looks for "gwan" or "g-wan" in the actual text of the question. If you want to search for the tag [tag:g-wan], you have to actually search for `[g-wan]`, but searching for `[gwan]` (the synonymous tag) would return the exact same results. It doesn't achieve anything.